# S3 Node.js SDK, LastModified date format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I'm using the S3 SDK for Node to make a request and list bucket contents (photos). I then need to **sort** these contents based on the `LastModified` date. This is the format of the date it's returning (which  I'm not really sure what that format even is/why AWS is doing it like that:

```
Tue Jul 05 2016 11:00:52 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

I tried using the `Date.parse()` method and using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to parse but to no avail.

In fact, Moment says it's an invalid date:

```
var day = moment("Tue Jul 05 2016 11:00:52 GMT-0400 (EDT)").isValid(); // false
```

Has anyone else experienced this before with the S3 Node SDK? And why is the date formatted like this?

Comment: You're going to have to specify the date format for the parser to know how to parse it. As per the Moment.js documentation "If you know the format of the date string that you will be parsing, it is always the best choice to explicitly specify that format." I would read about how to specify the format here: http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/

Comment: @MarkB, yes that's what I thought. But Moment.js doesn't have formatting for that above combination, like "Tue" and "Jul" (month name instead of number)

Comment: Yes they do, read the documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property), it's already a `Date` object... seems like you should not need to parse it, if the docs are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to parse your date correctly:

```
moment('Tue Jul 05 2016 11:00:52 GMT-0400 (EDT)', 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ')
```

Answer (score 3):

When I looked at this today, I noticed the format of an object's `LastModified` date in S3 is not the same as what was originally posted. This is the response I got back from S3: (notice the day and month are flipped)

`LastModified: 'Mon, 06 Feb 2017 00:00:35 GMT'`

So I had to update the format based on the answer from @idbehold

`const lastModified = moment(result.LastModified, 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ');`